# does not eval to a function error in couch db

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I'm using Couchdb 1.6.1. I have a show inside `test` design.

```
{
   "select": {
       "map": "function(a){emit(null,a._id)}"
   }
}
```

i'm using `Nano` Node modules to interact with the database. When i run js file below this `{ Error: Expression does not eval to a function. ([object Object])` error message is returned.

```
this.database.show('test', 'select', 35435156453, function (error, body) {
  if(error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
  else{
      console.log(body);
  }
});
```

I tried wrapping up the function with parentheses like below. That didn't work

```
{
   "select": {
       "map": "(function(a){emit(null,a._id)})"
   }
}
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, you are using a show function as if it were a view function (which is completely different).

If you really want to use a show "function", then I suggest you get a look into [this documentation.](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions) Show function are used to return data as HTML or with any formatting your require. You normally define a show function like this:

```
{
    "select":"function(doc,req){return 'Return your stuff here.'}"
}
```

The function you provided us is a mapping function which is used in views. See [this link](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/couchapp/ddocs.html#view-functions) for further documentation.  If it's the case, you would only need to use `this.database.view()` I guess.